# Javascript - How parse each json object as text string

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have my html working with javascript, and the file manifest.json to be read.

Here is my json file's code:

```
{
    "name": "Project",
    "description": "A template project",
    "icon": "img/icon.svg",
    "version": "X.X.X.X",
    "developer": {
        "name": "Daniell Mesquita",
        "url": "http://about.me/daniellmesquita"
    },
    "shop_id": "1",
    "manifest_version": 1,
    "default_language": "en"
}
```

I need read each object as text, parsing in javascript. Example:

```
<h1>+ name +</h1>
<h2>+ description +</h2>
<img src="+ icon +"/>
<p>+ version +</p>
```

Too, how can I read sub-objects of "developer" object?

**EDIT**: Validated json. Thanks to [@ADreNaLiNe-DJ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5119765/adrenaline-dj) and [Curious Concept's JSON Formater](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) for helping validate.

Comment: Have you tried reading it yourself? Share your idea/code. We can help you improve, not give the code

Comment: var name = myJsonObject.name;

Comment: After you parse the JSON into an object, use  `object.developer.name`

Comment: As far as i see, you have some typo (eg. `},`in the end) in you file.

Comment: `developer.name`, `developer.url`, ... should work.

Comment: @Mikelis Baltruks I know that "StackOverflow is not a writing service", but how improve a thing I don't know how do from base?

Comment: Have you heard about google? Check some options and try them out.

Comment: @MikelisBaltruks I know that you want reply at last and be the reason. Sinism can't do constructive discussions and can't solve problems. I simply can't reply to your sinism, or I can be equal. I and other people contributing with this question don't want flame discussions. You can reply at last and dream that you is with the reason, ok.

Comment: The problem with questions like these is that you only give us what you have, and where you want to go. From that context nobody can judge your amount of experience with the technology, and thus an answer could be either too simplistic or too complicated. You need to formulate a clear problem statement, not just "how to make this work". What is your real problem? Reading the json input? Looping? Accessing the json data? Writing to DOM? All or some of the previous? We just can't know.

Comment: I just googled _parse json object javascript_. In first 3 links I got the answer that is provided by Davide and that gets you what you want. I am just saying that a little effort and failure is what is expected before asking for help in SOF.

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ Yes, I've now removed the `},` from end of file, thanks!

Comment: As you haven't updated your question to what it is that you're not getting to work, I'll advice you to use a library. [mustache.js](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js) is a good choice. [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/vw9e1h8x/).

Comment: @Yoshi, my `manifest.json` file is togheter my index.html file, locally. I need load the local json file instead of using inline `var input = {}`.

Comment: You see now, how none of us could have actually answered your question completely? Even if it seems tedious, you really need to explain everything so that people know where you struggle. If you don't, then your question just reeks of "gimme the codes!", even if that's not your intention.

Answer (score 0):

If the json is in a String variable convert it to an object. Then you can access the single values:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(jsonString);

var name = obj.name;
var version = obj.version;
var developerName = obj.developer.name;
```

---

Comment: Thanks. I've now validated with helps.

Comment: How can I load from local `manifest.json` file? And how can I load the phrases as `+ phrase +` strings in HTML? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is stored as local file in same root of project, togheter the `index.html`, not in a remote/external server.

Answer (score 0):

You might do like the following. It will get your object key value pairs flattened even if you have nested objects in your data structure.

```js
var data = {
                       "name": "Project",
                "description": "A template project",
                       "icon": "img/icon.svg",
                    "version": "X.X.X.X",
                  "developer":
                             {
                              "name": "Daniell Mesquita",
                               "url": "http://about.me/daniellmesquita"
                             },
                    "shop_id": "1",
           "manifest_version": "1",
           "default_language": "en",
           },
stack = [[],[]];

function getKeyValuePairs(obj,stack) {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach( e => obj[e] instanceof Object ? getKeyValuePairs(obj[e], stack) : (stack[0].push(e), stack[1].push(obj[e])));
}
getKeyValuePairs(data, stack);

document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(stack,null,2) + "</pre>");
```

Comment: How can I load from local `manifest.json` file instead of using inline `var data = {}`? And how can I load the phrases as `+ phrase +` strings in HTML? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use 
`yourJsonVarName.developer.name`
`yourJsonVarName.developer.url`

[try this](https://jsfiddle.net/xeno13grin/x23zLcbe/)!

**Added**

If your external file is in your domain maybe you can use this to retrieve your data inside json file.

```
    $.getJSON( "manifest.json", function( data ) {
        var name = data.developer.name;
        var url = data.developer.url;
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! But I need use strings like `+ phrase +` in HTML. How can I load from the local `manifest.json` file instead of using `var json = {}`?